# getting unknown column error even when the column is present in mysql table

Tags: mysql

```
select tab1.*(
        select a.*
        from fw_invi a left join fw_resp b on a.id=b.did,
             fw_resp fra left join(
                           select *
                           from fw_type
                          ) tab4 on fra.qaild=tab4.qdetailid //this causing error

      )tab1 left join jos_users u on tab1.consu=u.id order by tab1.createdon desc
```

On running the above query in mysql i am getting the following error,which should not be the case as the specified missing column is present in that table.i think i am doing the wrong nested table aliasing.

```
Unknown column 'tab4.qdetailid' in 'on clause'
```

**1.Why i am getting the error even though the column is present.?**

**2.Is my above query syntax correct?**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you share you tables' DDLs? Or better yet, an [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com)?

Comment: i didn't see the reason of nesting the tables in query when you are selecting all data from tables then why you are writing nested queries  do the direct joins on table

Comment: @Mureinik thanks for the response but i cant put the tables in fiddle as the original tables conatin hundreds of column,this is just the simplified version of my query which i am writing.

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid thanks for the response but i have to left join because of the application need

Comment: do not use irrelevant tags. this question is NOT PHP related

Answer (score 0):

`*` can't  be used with  aliases. Aliases are used for named  columns.